# Apache .htaccess password protect with relative path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-authentication

I want to create a .htaccess file in my DocumentRoot, so that the directory is password protected.

But the password file, I want to specify by using the relative path of DocumentRoot.

So, if I am checking out the code in another system, it just works as it is. The password file will be part of my source control.

How can I access the parent directory of the DocumentRoot from .htaccess file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess AuthUserFile relative path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111627/htaccess-authuserfile-relative-path)

Answer (score 7):

I don’t think that’s possible. The [`AuthUserFile` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile) requires the file-path to be either absolute (thus from file system root) or relative from the [server root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serverroot).

Answer (score 6):

The AuthUserFile paths are relative to the server root (`/etc/apache2/` on Debian), or absolute.

To take care of different servers, you can use `IfDefine` directives with different variables on each server - see [my blog post](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/relative-htpasswd-path.htm) about that.

Comment: nice solution for dev/live environments.