# .htaccess not working on apache24

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I am trying to rewrite the url for a rest call (backend written in php). 
The problem is, that the .htaccess file is not working, or the file in general is ignored by the server.

## What i've tried

I've edited the httpd.conf file and changend following lines:

```
<Directory />
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

i also added a `Directory` Tag for my specific folder:

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/my/path/backend/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Because i am using the `RewriteEngine` i had to enable this module in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

## Infos

I'm working on Windows 10 machine.
My Apache version is: 2.4.16 Win32

## Problem

The problem is that the server ignores the `.htaccess` file. I know that because i tried to change the `DefaultIndex` with following line:

```
DirectoryIndex startPage.html
```

without any success.

Comment: I don't think `${SRVROOT}` will resolve to anything.

Comment: @anubhava `${SRVROOT}` is defined at the beginning of the conf file: `Define SRVROOT "/Apache24"`

Comment: Have you installed mod_define ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo there is no module for define. I looked it up and it's in the core of apache 2.4 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#define

Comment: IfDefine not work for me, maybe reason is that this directive only responds to parameters passed at the command line, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073752/apache-ifdefine-conditionals-in-htaccess

Comment: I don't think your `SRVROOT` is correct. You are on a windows box not a linux. You said it's `Define SRVROOT "/Apache24"` Windows uses the drive letter, you need it to be `Define SRVROOT "C:/Apache24"` or whatever drive you have it on.