# How to add Apache2 (XAMPP) runtime argument in Windows

Tags: apache, xampp, apache2

I am trying to set development variable for xampp under Windows in order to do this:

```
<IfDefine !development>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Say the secret word"
  AuthUserFile /var/www/hostname/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

on Linux you do it like this

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS=-Ddevelopment
```

How do I do this on Windows? I've tried to do

```
set APACHE_ARGUMENTS=-Ddevelopment
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Edit: tried to add startup parameters to apache service config, but didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate of [Apache .htaccess - applying basic authentication conditionally based on environment or hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073752/apache-htaccess-applying-basic-authentication-conditionally-based-on-environm)

I have solved this issue by using the 'Allow from ....' directive.

This way I can blanket enable based off an IP ADDRESS

Here is the contents of my ***.htaccess*** file

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/file/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```