# htaccess point to password file with a relative path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

in htaccess file is it possible to use relative paths?
i'm looking to see if exists any way to use relative paths so i would not change them on a new server

```
AuthUserFile {WEBSPACEROOT} auth/.password
AuthGroupFile {WEBSPACEROOT} auth/.group

AuthName "Reserved Area"
AuthType Basic
```

WEBSPACEROOT is my web server root

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess AuthUserFile relative path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111627/htaccess-authuserfile-relative-path)

Comment: You really shouldn't have your password file in the web root at all.  This is not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, **but** i wouldnt recommend it.  They have to be relative to the ServerRoot which is defined in the apache docs as

```
The ServerRoot directive sets the directory in which the server lives. Typically it will contain the subdirectories conf/ and logs/. 
Relative paths in other configuration directives (such as Include or LoadModule, for example) are taken as relative to this directory.
```

Is there any reason you require them to be relative? it would be easier to understand if you used the full path.

Comment: on development i use a protecter folder, that i upload on server, different serve of different hosting and i need to correct each time the path, or i can use the same folder on local machine, staging server and production server.